# .net core 2.0 windows impersonation

Tags: windows-authentication, asp.net-core-2.0, iis-8, .net-core-2.0

I'm new to .NetCore 2.0. I'm building a simple HR application that runs on our intranet in VS2017/C#.

Server: Window 2012 R2 
Using IIS as a reverse proxy. 
Windows Authentication only -- all other authentication disabled. 
.Net Core Windows server hosting on the server is 2.0.5.

In previous application (.net framework). I simply set the authentication on the site to windows, disabled all other authentication and set the identity impersonate = true in the web.config.

In .NET core, this is not working when the application attempts to access the database. In this case, I get an error stating that the IIS user cannot access the database (which they shouldn't be allowed to, the current windows login credentials should be used instead).

I have already done what it says in this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?tabs=aspnetcore2x

I am still getting an error stating that the IIS user cannot get access to the db, but I want it to impersonate the windows credential, not the IIS user.

In short, how do I get windows authentication to work in .NET Core 2?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The documentation is so clear that impersonation is not provided by default, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?tabs=aspnetcore2x#impersonation You might use some workarounds, like https://github.com/lilpug/ASP.NET-Core-Impersonation but mind the restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for the link Lex Li, I will have a look.

Comment: @LexLi The doc is clear on just the very fact that it doesn't support it, but gives no clue why or proper alternatives to implementation. The example it provides doesn't do it justice. Why is this previously trivially simple thing so much more complicated in .NET Core now?